# Confundido con sistema de menues

Tags: php, html5

Les comento que estoy un poco confundido en cuanto a un sistema de menús que estoy implementando en mi aplicación web. El tema es así:

1) Tengo una página index que incluye una cabecera y un menú básico que apunta a varias páginas (pongamoles los nombres A, B y C por ejemplo). En ese menú básico también se incluye la opción de ingresar al sistema.

2) Cuando el usuario ingresa o se registra va a parar a una página de destino, una landing page y el menu reacciona de acuerdo al tipo de usuario que ingresó. La landing page es como la index pero incluye este nuevo menú.

3) Esta página destino también tiene vínculos a esas páginas A, B y C a las que podía acceder desde el index... por lo tanto el menú debería reaccionar de acuerdo al usuario logueado.

```
<?php
session_start(); //Iniciar una nueva sesión o reanudar la existente

require 'includes/conexion.php';
include 'includes/funcs.php';

if(isset($_SESSION["id_usuario"])){ //En caso de existir la sesión redireccionamos
    // Está logueado cargo el menú que sería para el tipo de usuario
} else{
    // No está logueado cargo el menú basico
}
?>
```

Mi consulta es:  suponiendo que haga esto en el index directamente ¿ funcionará (todavía no probé) ? es decir, sin necesitar de "duplicar" la página destino, ¿ podría aplicarlo también al resto de las "n" páginas ?

Pregunta aparte, todos los post que tengo en los distintos formularios, ¿ siempre me conviene procesarlos en archivos php aparte ?

Desde ya les agradezco de antemano la ayuda que puedan darme...

---

Estoy teniendo algun que otro problema ya que en el formulario de login hago un session_star() porque analizo si el usuario esta logueado y tengo que hacer si o si un session_start()

```
session_start(); //Iniciar una nueva sesión o reanudar la existente
require 'includes/conexion.php';
include 'includes/funcs.php';

 if(isset($_SESSION["id_usuario"])){ //En caso de existir la sesión redireccionamos
    header("Location: 1908index.php");
 }
```

(la pagina 1908index.php es el index final de la página)

Más abajo, en el body cargo el menú:

```
<?php
  include 'menu.php';
?>
```

pero en el menu.php también tengo que manejar variables de session por lo tanto tengo que hacer otro session_start() puesto que si no lo hago, todo lo que tengo lo ignora !!!... 
cómo tendría que hacer ?

```
//session_start(); //Iniciar una nueva sesión o reanudar la existente  
//require 'includes/conexion.php';
//include 'includes/funcs.php';
include_once("includes/analyticstracking.php");

if(isset($_SESSION["id_usuario"])){ 
  if($_SESSION['tipo_usuario']==1) { ?>
```

etc etc etc
terminé comentando las líneas de session_start() porque me arroja un error de que la session ya esta iniciada, pero aún así ignora todo lo que esta debajo...

Comment: La respuesta corta es si, a las 2. Puedes crear un condicional para mostrar o no partes del menú u otras cosas. Y también es recomendable procesar los datos de los formularios en un archivo aparte.

Comment: Ok, ok, estoy probando y tengo problemas con los session_start(); ya que por ejemplo lo tengo en el formulario de login por ejemplo y tambien tengo que usarlo en la comprobación del menú... Me aparece el mensaje de error de  "A session had already been started - ignoring session_start()"

Comment: Eso es por que estás llamando 2 veces la sesión,  solo es necesario una por ejecución.  por eso te da ese error.

Comment: ¿Qué error es exactamente el que te muestra por pantalla, si es que te muestra alguno?

Comment: "A session had already been started - ignoring session_start()"